# Skip/bypass approval process

Tags: visualforce, trigger, approval-process

I want to skip/bypass an approval process by using some other VF page/apex class/trigger, is it possible ? what kind of framework should I think of ?
Basically I want the record to be editable, even when it goes to an approval process !! I have 6 different segment users to use the approval process functionality simultaneously. 
So I would want to use an approach which is not native salesforce and maybe done using triggers and workflows.